# Spring MVC project cannot use Hibernate

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I want to build a Spring MVC project with Hibernate.

The IDE I used is Eclipse 4.4.2(Luna) and I installed the plugin [Spring Tool Suite (STS) for Eclipse Luna (4.4)](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tool-suite-sts-eclipse-luna-44).

The project I create is **Spring project** > **Spring MVC Project**.

[image: create project]

Here is the External Jars I add :

- antlr-2.7.7.jar
- dom4j-1.6.1.jar
- hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar
- hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar
- hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
- jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar
- javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
- jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar
- jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar
- jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
- mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar

Then, I add the detail of my database into **/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml** :

```xml
<beans:bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.43/MyDatabase" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="testUser" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="thePassOfTheUser" />
</beans:bean>
```

However, it shows the error message :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory


java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDataSource.<init>(AbstractDataSource.java:37)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.<init>(DriverManagerDataSource.java:87)
```

Since I cannot fix it, I tried write **hibernate.cfg.xml**, but I have no idea where the file should be put.

I want to know **how to set the bean to let my project can use Hibernate** and **how to use transitional way of hibernate (hibernate.cfg.xml) in the MVC project**.

---

**May 19th added**

I found the solution.

It is because maven didn't load hibernate. Therefore after adding the following code into pom.xml it can work:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager‌​</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.‌​hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0.Final</v‌​ersion>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</‌​artifactId>
    <version>1.3.156</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.spring‌​framework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</ve‌​rsion>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Missing `commons-logging` jar. Try to add `commons-logging-1.1.1.jar` in your **Classpath**.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is related to missing library in classpath. Which is:

```
org.apache.commons.logging
```

Try to fix that first then tell if problem still occurs.

Comment: The original project has already included it. In **Maven Dependencies** has **jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar** . [The jar list of Maven Dependencies](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-X7bcsGlcMro/VVHFfuMdGzI/AAAAAAAAAFI/rAqpJ1Q_d7g/s0/M.png)

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace says that you're missing LogFactory which is part of Apache Commons Logging. I don't see it included in your external jars.

For the transitional way of hibernate create hibernate.cfg.xml configuration file and place it in the root of your application's classpath. 
The XML configuration file must conform to the Hibernate 3 Configuration DTD, which is available from http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd.

[Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_configuration.htm) is a tutorial on it.

Comment: @Shiyou Can we have a look at where you add your logging dependencies in your pom.xml ? (i comment here, can't comment above :/)

Comment: I didn't change anything for my pom.xml. 
I have uploaded my source code into googledrive [link 1](https://googledrive.com/host/0B-JxQ6gkhUkjfmlLZEZBS2JFNUJVRlMyV0R3aEVRb0YwQW5hQl9BS3RlV0syeTZaY0VTVGc/), [link 2](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-JxQ6gkhUkjfmlLZEZBS2JFNUJVRlMyV0R3aEVRb0YwQW5hQl9BS3RlV0syeTZaY0VTVGc&usp=sharing). (link 1 is host view, so it maybe need to login to see.)

Comment: can you try to precise <scope>runtime</scope> for log4J dependency and see if it changes as they said [here](http://spring.io/blog/2009/12/04/logging-dependencies-in-spring/)

Comment: You mean like this: `<dependency><groupId>log4j</groupId><artifactId>log4j</artifactId><version>1.2.15</version> ... <scope>runtime</scope></dependency>` ? I tried but it still shows the same error message.

Comment: Then it really seems to be commons-logging 1.1.1 that is missing in your maven dependencies. jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar may be incomplete on it try to add commons-logging 1.1.1 `<dependency>
   <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
  </dependency>` to your pom.xml . I've got a project working with same dependencies as yours and with this one.

Comment: It shows `Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for commons-logging:commons-logging:jar is missing.` even if I add commons-logging-1.2.jar. Also, since I got error message (before I ask the question, I got this issue) when I run the program, I think I should give it. I save it as pdf file and put it into google drive: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-JxQ6gkhUkjZEVaX1c5dTYtM0k/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: and clean install it after?   Seems that he didn't downloaded jars

Comment: I found the solution. I add the code `<dependency><groupId>org.hibernate</groupId><artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId><version>3.6.0.Final</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>org.hibernate</groupId><artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId><version>3.6.0.Final</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>com.h2database</groupId><artifactId>h2</artifactId><version>1.3.156</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>org.springframework</groupId><artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId><version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version></dependency>` into pom.xml and update maven, then the program can run

Comment: However, if I want to use Hibernate, I need to put hibernate.cfg.xml in the project. Can anyone tell me how to move hibernate.cfg.xml code into my context.xml file like the code in this page : http://openhome.cc/Gossip/SpringGossip/SessionFactoryInjection.html  ?